# Ruby on rails - Form not creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im totally new to Ruby on rails and im trying to make a simple form.this is my code. but the form is not creating. help me out

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<% form_for :post do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>


    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>


    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try `<%= form_for :post do |f| %>`

Comment: thank you so much @jvillian

Comment: Sure thing. I added it as an answer. Please feel free to upvote/accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try <%= form_for :post do |f| %>

When you have `<%= ... %>`, it creates output.

When you have `<% ... %>`, it executes the ruby code, but creates no output.